# getaddrinfo: in what way is AI_PASSIVE ignored if the nodename is specified?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, posix

Quoting from the specs of [getaddrinfo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freeaddrinfo.html):

> If the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is specified, the returned address information shall be suitable for use in binding a socket for accepting incoming connections for the specified service. In this case, if the `nodename` argument is null, then the IP address portion of the socket address structure shall be set to `INADDR_ANY` for an IPv4 address or `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` for an IPv6 address.

This makes sense. If you specify `AI_PASSIVE`, you can `bind()`/`listen()`/`accept()` on the returned address. If `nodename` is null, the returned address binds to all network interfaces so you can use any of the computer's IP addresses (e.g. ethernet LAN IP, Wi-Fi LAN IP, loopback address, etc.). Summary: use `AI_PASSIVE` on the server (for a TCP socket).

Continuing:

> If the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is not specified, the returned address information shall be suitable for a call to `connect()` (for a connection-mode protocol) or for a call to `connect()`, `sendto()`, or `sendmsg()` (for a connectionless protocol). In this case, if the `nodename` argument is null, then the IP address portion of the socket address structure shall be set to the loopback address.

This also makes sense. If you **don't** specify `AI_PASSIVE`, you can `connect()`/`sendto()`/`sendmsg()` on the returned address. If `nodename` is null, you get the loopback address. Summary: **don't** use `AI_PASSIVE` on the client (for a TCP socket).

Continuing:

> The `AI_PASSIVE` flag shall be ignored if the `nodename` argument is not null.

Huh? What does it even mean to *ignore* the `AI_PASSIVE` flag? From the first two quotes, it sounds like `AI_PASSIVE` is only used to determine whether you get addresses suitable for server/client use, and in both of those cases it sounds like a null `nodename` just gives you a `INADDR_ANY` address (for server) or loopback address (for client). What good does it do to *ignore* the `AI_PASSIVE` flag?

What does this last quote really mean? How does it affect the first two quotes?

Answer (score 4):

The Linux manpage for `gettaddrinfo(2)` describes it slightly differently (and a bit more consistently):

> If  the  **AI_PASSIVE**  flag  is specified in *hints.ai_flags*, and *node* is NULL, then the returned socket addresses will be suitable for **bind**(2)ing a socket that will  **accept**(2)  connections. The returned socket address will contain the "wildcard address" [...]. If *node* is not NULL, then the **AI_PASSIVE** flag is ignored.
>
> If the **AI_PASSIVE** flag is not set in *hints.ai_flags*, then the returned socket addresses will be suitable for use with **connect**(2), **sendto**(2), or **sendmsg**(2).  If *node* is NULL, then the network address will be set to the loopback interface address [...].

Of course, the Linux manpage is not authoritative other than for Linux, but I offer it as a widely-used interpretation.  In particular, note that it specifies that you get a server socket only if AI_PASSIVE is given **and** *node* is NULL.  That still leaves some ambiguity as to what it means to "ignore" AI_PASSIVE, but I think it nevertheless points to the interpretation taken by Linux: you always get address info suitable for a client socket if *node* is not NULL.

You could perhaps rationalize it this way: "The AI_PASSIVE flag shall be ignored" should be interpreted as "if the AI_PASSIVE flag is set then that fact shall be ignored".  That is, it shall be handled as if the flag were not set.  I think that's additionally supported by the fact that this statement occurs in the same paragraph with the description of the behavior when AI_PASSIVE is set (in the official docs too, not just the Linux manpage).

Comment: So, to sum it up, the only time `AI_PASSIVE` is ever useful is when you're creating a server socket and want it to bind to all interfaces (so you'd pass in `NULL` for `nodename`)? That's kind of lame. Why on earth would it ever be useful compared to just using `INADDR_ANY`/`IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` directly?

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` populates other fields, not just the IP address.  So it can still be useful to use `getaddrinfo()` with a NULL `nodename` instead of populating the `sockaddr` manually.

Comment: If `nodename` is not NULL, and `AI_NUMERICHOST` is not specified, a DNS lookup is performed. It does not make sense to do that for a passive listening socket. On the other hand, if `nodename` is an IP address, and `AI_NUMERICHOST` is specified, it doesn't matter if `AI_PASSIVE` is specified or not, the IP address is returned as-is, and can be used equally for `bind()`, `connect()`, `sendto()`, etc, `getaddrinfo()` doesn't care. Remember, `AI_PASSIVE` is just a **hint**, it does not apply to everything.