# How to choose a server socket address using getaddrinfo?

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming, posix, getaddrinfo

I would like to create a TCP server application which lets the user choose the local address that is used in the bind call. The user may provide a textual representation of a host name or IP address, so I thought of using the getaddrinfo function to translate the textual representation into one or several sockaddr structs (performing name lookup if necessary).

Now here's my problem: The getaddrinfo function does not seem to suit my needs, because it requires the AI_PASSIVE flag to be set in the hints structure in order to obtain socket addresses that may be used in bind calls. But if I use AI_PASSIVE, I can not use the nodename parameter anymore, which defeats the whole purpose of letting the user choose the local address. If I do not provide AI_PASSIVE, getaddrinfo will only return those addresses which can be used in connect, sendto and sendmsg calls, but there might be addresses that can be used for binding but not for connect, sendto or sendmsg calls, which would be omitted. See the POSIX specification regarding the [getaddrinfo/freeaddrinfo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html) functions.

To clarify my needs, here is a sketch of the application I am trying to create:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s address port\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    struct addrinfo *result;
    /* The next line won't work as intended! It will behave as if the
    AI_PASSIVE flag was not set. */
    if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result) != 0) {
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Iterate result list */
    int sfd;
    struct addrinfo *rp = result;
    do {
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break; /* Success */

        close(sfd);
        rp = rp->ai_next;
    } while (rp != NULL);

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (rp == NULL) { /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ... use socket bound to sfd ... */

    close(sfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I actually have several questions regarding the topic. First off, *why* is the nodename parameter forbidden when using the AI_PASSIVE flag? What is the intention? It does not make any sense to me. Is there any (preferably POSIX-conform) way to find local addresses that I can bind to and that correspond to a given host name or IP address in textual representation at all? Provided that the given nodename corresponds to a local address and AI_PASSIVE is *not* set, will there be any addresses returned by getaddrinfo, that can not be used for binding? Or worse, will there be any addresses that are only suitable for binding and that will not be returned in this case?

Related (and not answered satisfactorily): [getaddrinfo: in what way is AI_PASSIVE ignored if the nodename is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829275/getaddrinfo-in-what-way-is-ai-passive-ignored-if-the-nodename-is-specified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree the reference question was not answered satisfactorily and IMO the whole feature is poorly specified.

I believe the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is misnamed. It should be called something like `AI_ANY_ADDRESS`. It just means "give me a token I can use to bind to any node address on this system (within the address family, etc)" so that you don't have to hard-code `INADDR_ANY` and `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`.  Hence, if you supply a node name argument, you're obviating the point of `AI_PASSIVE`. You're saying "Here's the address(es) I want to bind to".

In practice, this all works out fine because the structure of addresses accepted by `bind` and `connect` is fundamentally the same in all cases (except that you can't `connect` to the special "any" address). That's why -- when you specify the node name -- it doesn't matter whether you specify `AI_PASSIVE` or not. You're going to get the parameters appropriate for a `bind` or `connect` call on the specified name/address.

Obtaining that "address info" doesn't mean the `bind` or `connect` will succeed. You could successfully obtain an address that you can't `bind` to -- because it's not an address of the local machine -- or for other reasons as well. (And obviously, the `connect` could fail for many reasons as well -- there might be no machine answering at that address or no server listening on the port, etc.)

If you supply a node name that is not an IP address and name resolution provides multiple IP addresses in different families (that are all available on the local machine), you should be able to `bind` to all of those addresses.

So, bottom line: If you want to allow the user to specify the address, just provide that to `getaddrinfo`. The address(es) you get back (if any) should be usable in a `bind` call.

Comment: So the spec making this distinction between addresses for binding/connecting is just plain misleading and makes no sense. Without this distinction, the AI_PASSIVE flag as a simple abstraction for INADDR_ANY/IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT is still useful in its own right and all use cases are satisfied. Thank you for this great explanation!