# Getting strange addresses from getaddrinfo

Tags: sockets, unix, unix-socket

I wrote the following test program and can't understand the output I'm getting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct addrinfo* results;
  struct addrinfo hints;
  char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1];

  if (argc != 2) {
    exit(-1);
  }

  memset((char*) &hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  int ret = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &results);
  if (ret) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
    exit(-1);
  }

  for (struct addrinfo* ai = results; ai != NULL; ai = ai->ai_next) {
    if (ai->ai_family == AF_INET) {
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, ai, buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    } else {
      inet_ntop(AF_INET6, ai, buf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buf);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(results);
  return 0;
}
```

On my Fedora 23 machine, this will print:

```
1.0.0.0
100:0:a00:0:100:0:600:0
```

My understanding is that the IP addresses returned should be `INADDR_ANY` and `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`, both of which should have the value `0`, i.e. the expected output should be `0.0.0.0` and `::0`. Could someone explain to me what's going on here?

Another related question is that if one of my interfaces has an IP that `host.domain.dom` resolves to and I'm not a priori sure if the domain has an IPv6 address or not, how can I get `sockaddr` structs that I can use to listen to both the IPv4 and IPv6 address for this domain, but without binding to any other IP? Is it correct to provide that host name to `getaddrinfo` even though the `AI_PASSIVE` flag gets ignored in this case?

Answer (score 4):

You should not be providing `ai` itself as the argument to `inet_ntop`; you should be providing a pointer to the actual network address, not a pointer to your `addrinfo` struct.  `inet_ntop()` expects `in_addr` and `in6_addr` structs, so type-cast `ai->ai_addr` to either `sockaddr_in*` or `sockaddr_in6*` based on the `ai->ai_family`, and then pass the address of its `sin_addr` or `sin6_addr` field, respectively.

```
if (ai->ai_family == AF_INET) {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((sockaddr_in*)(ai->ai_addr))->sin_addr), buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
} else {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((sockaddr_in6*)(ai->ai_addr))->sin6_addr), buf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
}
```

For your second question, I believe this will answer it:

[How to choose a server socket address using getaddrinfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028467/65863)